# CLR Profiling and Rewriting using ICLRProfiling::AttachProfiler()

Tags: c#, .net, profiling, clr, clr-profiling-api

I gather the main benefit of using the CLR Profiler [ICLRProfiling::AttachProfiler](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd695930(v=vs.110).aspx) method is that you now can attach your CLR profiler long *after* the target process has started **and** that you also don't have to pass the `COR_ENABLE_PROFILING` and `COR_PROFILER` environment variables to the process at launch? Are both of these correct assumptions?

Also, I've read in a CLR Profiling team [blog post from 2011](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/davbr/2009/11/04/clr-v4-profiler-attach-basics-with-sample-code/) that [ICLRProfiling::AttachProfiler](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd695930(v=vs.110).aspx) did not support the following but would in the future:

- `GetILFunctionBody`
- `GetILFunctionBodyAllocator`
- `SetILFunctionBody`
- `SetILInstrumentedCodeMap`
- `SetEnterLeaveFunctionHooks*`
- `SetFunctionIDMapper*`
- `GetNotifiedExceptionClauseInfo`
- All methods related to Enter/Leave/Tailcall

Are these supported now? I'm asking since I have'nt found anything more on the subject online and many of the Microsoft links from 2011-2012 are dead now. If  not, then is it even possible to IL rewrite a function body when using [ICLRProfiling::AttachProfiler](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd695930(v=vs.110).aspx) to attach my CLR Profiler?

Answer (score 1):

The answer was sadly "No", you can't do IL Rewriting when in CLR attach profiler mode; it is still only supported in process launch mode.

The call to the [`ICorProfilerInfo::GetILFunctionBody()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms233181(v=vs.110).aspx) method in my CLR Profiler implementation returns [`CORPROF_E_UNSUPPORTED_FOR_ATTACHING_PROFILER`](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/yizhang/2010/12/17/interpreting-hresults-returned-from-netclr-0x8013xxxx/) :

> GetILFunctionBody() failed with error 0x8013136f

the `ICorProfilerInfo::GetILFunctionBody()` [source is here](https://github.com/dotnet/coreclr/blob/0177a7affbe3c09c0be8b753e1907612fff62d46/src/vm/proftoeeinterfaceimpl.cpp) for those interested in digging into why this happens.